# .NET 4.0 Webservice and .NET framework 8 upgrade

Tags: .net, .net-4.8

I Have some web services (.asmx) that was build using .net framework 4.0
We are planning to upgrade the .net framework to 4.8.

There are no code changes.

In web.config - The change is made from targetFramework = 4.0 to 4.8

```
<compilation Debug="true" targetFramework = "4.8" />
```

The web services are running.

Does it mean the framework is upgraded to 4.8?

Comment: You can't upgrade the framework by building a project or running it.  It is done by Windows Update.  Which no doubt upgraded it to a version higher than 4.0 a very long time ago.  You only specify the *minimum* version you need in the config file.

Comment: Thank you. The app pool version in IIS is .NET CLR version v.4.0.30319. So 4.8 is not used?

Comment: All 4.x frameworks use runtime version 4.0.30319.  You are supposed to realize that you've been using 4.8 for quite a while already, you just never explicitly said that you needed it.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thank you.